# Get Userinfo from Oauth2 DocuSign API Implicit Grant

Tags: jquery, ajax, phonegap-build, docusignapi

I'm trying to get the userinfo from the DocuSign API after I receive the access token (response_type=token) from an Implicit Grant oauth2 call.

My code looks like the following:

```
request = $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
     xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', DSaccesstoken);
       },
     url: DSuserurl 
   });

request.done (function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
 alert(response); 
 }

request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   alert("Error retrieving DocuSign User Account Information: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + ". "); 
   });

});
```

A few points... DSaccesstoken is a variable that contains 'Bearer access token received from Docusign'.  The code executes successfully but the response data looks like html when its suppose to contain json.  I also tried `datatype: 'json'` but that doesn't work either. I also tried with `headers: {'Authorization': DSaccesstoken}` instead of beforeSend but that didn't work either.

I'm assuming the header is not being passed correctly to DocuSign but I'm not 100% sure.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?   FYI, I'm using PhoneGap Build service to create a mobile app.

Comment: Sorry, you need to provide more information.  It is not clear that the user has authenticated properly. Is he asked to log in?

Comment: More information:

Comment: More information: Apparently my code is passing the Authorization header correctly.   My DocuSign sandbox and integrator key is defined as "This is a Mobile App".  My return uri is http://localhost/callback. The problem is DocuSign is throwing the following error: {"errorCode":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","message":"The URL provided does not resolve to a resource."}  Has anyone received this error while trying to retrieve userinfo using implicit oauth?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The header should be {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + DSaccesstoken}.
2. DocuSign Rest API is NOT allowed from client-side, dur to CORS restriction. In case you are calling it from a browser-like side, you might considing setting up a proxy server (using node for instance). That proxy server will receive ajax calls and redirect them to DocuSign API. You can use [DocuSign official NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusign-esign).